# Is it possible to use write c code access rild socket in Android

Tags: android, c, sockets

like the Title. I write the code like this:

```
printf("create socket\r\n");

fd = socket_local_client(SOCKET_NAME_RIL,
ANDROID_SOCKET_NAMESPACE_RESERVED,
SOCK_STREAM);

if (fd < 0) {
perror ("opening radio  socket error");
exit(-1);
}



printf("fd = %d\r\n",fd);
int length = 12;
char datalength[5]={0};
datalength[0] = 0;
datalength[1] = 0;
datalength[2] = (length >>8) & 0xff;
datalength[3] = (length & 0xff);
int ret = send(fd, datalength, 4, 0);
if(ret != sizeof(int)) {
    perror ("Socket write error when sending length");
    close(fd);
    exit(-1);
}
```

i can get fd value successfully, and send data successfully.
but from "logcat -b radio" there is nothing information can be displayed.
it seems that rild has prevent socket connection.

is there any resolutions? Thanks

Comment: I am not able to parse your question heading.

Answer (score 0):

The **rild** socket is "owned" by the Phone app, so you won't be able to connect to it as long as that is running. You might try connecting to the **rild-debug** socket.